# when attempting to connect to facebook with PHP script endless redirects

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, redirect

first facebook asks me to click okay to authorize the app then chrome gives me this error. and the I have this endless redirect problem. I have read many cases about this but none clear and simple enough to get me over this obstacle.

The webpage at *_*__*_*__*_*__*_*&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmizu.net46.net%2Ffacebookpost6.php&state=***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3&req_perms=user_status%2Cpublish_stream%2Cuser_photos%2Coffline_access%2Cmanage_pages#*=*">https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=***_*__*_*__*_*__*_***&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmizu.net46.net%2Ffacebookpost6.php&state=***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3&req_perms=user_status%2Cpublish_stream%2Cuser_photos%2Coffline_access%2Cmanage_pages#*=* has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

what I know.

1. facebook.php is working
2. the secret and appid are being passed correctly by the script.
3. I  must have configured my app settings on the facebook development site almost correctly

how do I know this?

because when I change those variables in my script or adjust the settings
on facebook development server, I dont even get this far, I dont get asked to click ok or see my facebook profile in chrome.

what I dont know.

How to fix this redirect problem. or complete the authentication process. echo $user always returns 0.

my code looks like this:

```
  require 'src/facebook.php';

 $app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 $app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxx";


   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'cookie' => true

  ));

  $user = $facebook->getUser();
   echo $user;

 if(($facebook->getUser())==0)
{
 header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' =>           

  'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,offline_access,manage_pages'))}");

   exit;
 }


  thanks for any help
```

Answer (score 0):

changing the setting to no when asked" is this a desktop app? " in the advanced section of app configuration on developers.facebook.com seem to resolve this issue.